# How would I use the attribute as input for Value with JOLT?

Tags: jolt

For a specific function that I am building, I need to parse my JSON and have in some cases the attribute, instead of the value itself, be used as the value for the attribute. But how do I manage that with JOLT?

Let's say this is my input:

```
{
  "Results": [
    {
      "FirstName": "John",
      "LastName": "Doe"
    },
    {
      "FirstName": "Mary",
      "LastName": "Joe"
    },
    {
      "FirstName": "Thomas",
      "LastName": "Edison"
    }
  ]
}
```

And this should be the outcome:

```
{
  "Results": [
    {
      "Name": "FirstName",
      "Value": "John"
    },
    {
      "Name": "FirstName",
      "Value": "Mary"
    },
    {
      "Name": "FirstName",
      "Value": "Thomas"
    },
    {
      "Name": "LastName",
      "Value": "Doe"
    },
    {
      "Name": "LastName",
      "Value": "Doe"
    },
    {
      "Name": "LastName",
      "Value": "Edison"
    },
  ]
}
```

---

For those interested.. I'm building a JSON to Excel export functionality in Mendix and it has to be completely dynamic, regardless of the input. To accomplish this, I need an array where each attribute (equal to a column in Excel) has to be it's own object with a column name and a value. If each column data is it's own object, I can simply say "create column for each object with the same "Name". *Little bit difficult to explain, but it 'should' work.*

Answer (score 2):

Arrays and Jolt, are not the best.   Basically there are 3 ways to deal with arrays in Shift.

1. you explicitly assign data to an array position. Aka `foo[0]` and `foo[1]`
2. you reference a "number" that exists in the input data.  Aka `foo[&2]` and `foo[&3]`
3. you "accumulate" data into a list.   Aka `foo[]`.

Your input data is array of size `3`.  Your desired output is an array of size `6`.  You want this to be flexible and be able to handle variable inputs.

This means option 3.   So you have to "fix" / process your data into it "final form", while maintaining the original input Json structure (of a list with 3 items), and then accumulate all the "built" items into a list.

This means that you are buildling a list of lists, and then finally "squashing" it down to a single list.

Spec

```
[
  {
    // Step 1 : Pivot the data into parallel lists of keys and values
    //  maintaining the original outer input list structure.
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Results": {
        "*": { // results index
          "*": { // FirstName / Lastname
            "$": "temp[&2].keys[]",
            "@": "temp[&2].values[]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // Step 2 : Un-pivot the data into the desired
    //  Name/Value pairs, using the inner array index to 
    //  keep things organized/separated.
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "temp": {
        "*": { // temp index
          "keys": {
            "*": "temp[&2].[&].Name"
          },
          "values": {
            "*": "temp[&2].[&].Value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // Step 3 : Accumulate the "finished" Name/Value pairs
    //  into the final "one big list" output.
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "temp": {
        "*": { // outer array
          "*": "Results[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```